# Why flux less when area is bent?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

This is the continuation of my previous question and quite interestingly, I want to see electric flux definition with a different point of view.

Electric flux can be defined as electric field strength at each point of the surface and then summed it up. I want to follow this explanation and not how many field lines pass through the area.

Here is the image we can focus on.

[image]

Let's consider now 2 cases(one where surface is bent as on the image and one where it's not bent).

In both cases, surface contains the same amount of points(let's say 100 points). When it's not bent, we know that at each point of the surface's 100 points, there's electric field strength so we do 100*E to get flux. Now, it's bent. Note that there're still 100 points on the surface(we didn't make it smaller or bigger). Now, why would the flux be less ? From the image, it's clear(I know) that less lines pass, but I'm focusing on strength. If there're still 100 points, we should get 100*E. The only reason flux would be less than 100*E is if at some points of the surface, electric field strength is 0. There's no way it would be 0 at some points as at each point of 100, there'll still be electric field line there hence the strength. What am I missing?

Comment: Electric flux can be defined as electric field strength at each point of the surface and then summed it up.-  Are you sure about this. Since field strength is a scalar so it can be possible that the flux passing through a closed surface is 0 but the sum of the field strength at every point is not

Comment: It depends. We use EAcosa  to get flux (without integral in this case). If so, you can translate this formula into my definition. E is constant over the surface, A is the points count on the surface and if a=0, then we get EA which is exactly field strength summed it up.

Comment: I think what you're referring is a little bit different as with the formula of EAcosa, you wouldn't get flux to be 0. For closed surfaces, it has a slightly different idea

Comment: Why did you write down $EA\cos\alpha$ and then ignore the $\cos\alpha$? Clearly no longer the same value there

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I know that, but I'm trying to understand it with my definition as stated on the question and not by the definition of electric field lines passing through.

Comment: The picture you drew very clearly has a different $\cos\alpha$ than 1. I have not invoked any electric field _lines_ or anything yet, just pointing out the geometry you drew

Comment: I get the geometry, but i explain on the question what my confusion is. hard to explain it again in the reply. maybe you didn't understand the question ?

Comment: I might not be understanding the question, but I think you're just misunderstanding a *heuristic* for how to understand electric flux.  Electric flux is *defined* as the dot product of the electric field and the area vector.  That is the *useful* quantity, because that's what appears in Gauss's Law. The *heuristic* for understanding what it means is that it measures the "amount" of electric field that "pierces" the surface, but understand that this is just a way of trying to get a *feeling* for what flux means, and is not the *definition* of flux.  Therefore, you're doing things backwards.

Comment: The point is, you've defined a quantity that *isn't* flux, and the quantity you've defined turns out not to be useful.

Comment: @Chemistry  as with the formula of EAcosa, you wouldn't get flux to be 0- but you do. And  there is no different idea for closed surfaces. Over there also we are summing up the flux passing through small areas of the surface. If flux is just the strength of the field at a small area of the surface then it should be positive or 0 regardless of the  surface being closed or open. But in reality in a closed surface, part of the surface has positive flux while the other has negative and hence it cancels out to become 0. Ofcourse I am assuming that there is no charge present inside the body

Comment: And if your definition is wrong there can be  no  answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What matters is not the area of the frame but the cross-section of it exposed to $\vec E$. This is why there is a dot product $\vec E\cdot d\vec S$ in the expression for the (infinitesimal) flux.

The cross-sectional area of the frame exposed to the field lines of $\vec E$ is reduced when it is tilted, and it is reduced by an amount $\cos\alpha$ which is precisely the angle between $\vec E$ and $d\vec S$: remember that $d\vec S$ is *perpendicular* to the frame.

Imagine as a limiting case a situation where an ideal frame of negligible thickness is parallel to the electric field lines: clearly the flux would be $0$ in this case.

Comment: in my example, when surface is bent, we still got 100 points there. Why flux less here than when surface is perpendicular ? are you saying that when surface is bent, not all points of it have E > 0 ?

Comment: I don't mean cosa explanation. logically, per my definition, "Electric flux can be defined as electric field strength at each point of the surface and then summed it up.". When surface is bent, per my definition,  Electric field strength should be less at some points, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Chemistry Electric flux **cannot** be defined as the sum of the electric field strength at each point of the surface. That is simply not what flux is. What is summed over the surface is **not** the magnitude of the field at each point, but rather the *component* of the field which is perpendicular to the surface.

Comment: Yes, it's component of the field, but in my drawing above, electric field is in one direction(let's say x and not in 2 directions-x/y) so how can it have y component at all ?

Comment: @Chemistry It *doesn't* have a $y$-component, which is precisely why the flux decreases as you tilt the surface, and goes to zero when the surface is oriented entirely along $y$.

Comment: I think I know the confusion. Let me ask you this. let's consider 2 cases. 1 where surface is bent and one where it's not. are you saying less electric field lines pass through the area in case 1 than in 2 ?

Comment: @Chemistry The flux isn't just a point or line count, it's an orientation-dependent measure.   Not 'bent', but 'tilted', with that cosine factor (one when the field is perpendicular to the area-element-normal-vector direction, zero when it is parallel).

Comment: @Chemistry At your request, I haven't said anything about electric field lines, which should be understood primarily as illustrative visualization tools. If the surface is tilted as shown in your figure, then the flux is reduced because at each point, the **component** of the field perpendicular to the surface is reduced.  If you wish to describe things in terms of field lines, then yes, fewer field lines pass through the surface when it is tilted (as should be clear from visual inspection).

Comment: @J.Murray quick question - https://youtu.be/9MN0eTC-vzQ?t=556 on this link(exactly starts at the moment I want you to listen), his statement seems wrong to me. he says that because the area is tilted, the E lines that were contributing to the surface (when not tilted) no longer contribute. I think this is confusing as hell. Because even if area is tilted, the same number of electric field lines will still pass through it. The reason is there were infinite amount of field lines in space, so when tilted, there'll be E field lines that will still pass through the whole surface. Don't you agree ?

Comment: @Chemistry The field does not have a $\hat y$ component, but the surface area $d\vec S$ (which is a vector!)  does.  As a result, $\vec E\cdot d\vec S =E_x dS_x$ only picks up the $\hat x$-component of the vector $d\vec S$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero could you check my previous reply in this thread where I mention youtube ? i think that must be the reason of my confusion.

Comment: @Chemistry In your figure, if the surface were not tilted then the top and bottom lines would pass through it. Because it is tilted, they don't. I'm having a hard time understanding what the issue is. If your concern is that there should be an infinite number of field lines in both cases, then you're missing the point of field lines **as an intuitive visualization aid**. The definition of flux involves the dot product between the electric field and the area vector of the surface, full stop.

Comment: @J.Murray Yes, my concern is exactly what you said and due to my concern, the youtube video (what it says) is not definitely correct. Since there're infinite number of field lines(this means there's E at each point in the space), then if it got tilted, there would be another E line that would go through our tilted area. The thing now is in reality, in both cases, the same number of E lines pass through it. It's right that E that was passing in not tilted, wouldn't pass in tilted one, but in exchange, there would be a different E line for tilted. That was the whole confusion.

Comment: @Chemistry When we talk about "numbers of field lines", we are assuming that a finite number of them have been drawn in such a way that their relative closeness is an illustration of the strength of the field. It should be fairly obvious that you can't draw an infinite number of them. Again, they are a **visualization tool**, not the fundamental definition of flux. Also - no, that's not true. Every field line that passes through the tilted surface *also* passes through the untilted surface, but the reverse is (clearly) not true.

Comment: @Chemistry Even if we assume that there are infinite lines passing through, if the area had not been tilted then more no of lines would have been passing through the area. You cannot say that there are infinite lines passing through so it does not matter what the area is as the flux will be infinity. You can say that  there are x lines passing through a unit area where x is a very large number. Now the number of field lines passing is going to be x multiplied by the area of the sheet perpendicular to the field lines. If you tilit the sheet this area gets less.

Comment: @Chemistry also when you say that - It's right that E that was passing in not tilted, wouldn't pass in tilted one, but in exchange, there would be a different E line for tilted.- But how is it possible that that field line was not there when the sheet was untilited and that when it  became tilted that field line suddenly started hitting it?

Comment: @Obinna what I mean is if the area is tilted, there will still be electric field line at each point of the tilted surface. The same is true for "not" tilted area - there will be Electric field line at each point. What is the difference is the electric field line (specific one - E1) might have ended up at "not tilted" area, but wouldn't end up at "tilted area". I get that, but in exchange, there would definitely be electric field line that would hold the spot instead of E1.

Answer (score 0):

> Electric flux can be defined as electric field strength at each point
> of the surface and then summed it up.

Not for an electric flux.

That definition is suitable to describe a flow of heat for example. If we have two regions with different temperatures inside an insulated pipe, the area of the boundary matters, so a tilted section allows more heat flux. And we can say that the portion of the tilted section with the same area of an orthogonal section allows the same heat flux of it.

The intuition behind the electric flux is similar to a pipe with a flow of water. If we do an orthogonal or tilted imaginary cut at the middle of the pipe, the flow doesn't change while the boundary area changes. What matters is the cross section area.

Comment: I think better put, Electric flux can be defined as field strength of perpendicular component(Ey) at each point of the surface and then summed it up. Thoughts ?

Comment: That is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Electric flux can be defined as electric field strength at each **point**
> of the surface and then summed it up.

Electric flux is to do with areas and not points, which have no area, and more so, projected areas whose normals are parallel to the electric field.

So instead of your $100$ *points* you should consider $100$ *areas* and their appropriate projections to resolve your dilemma.